# Обращение к дочерней папке с неизвестным именем php

Tags: php

Уважаемые форумчане, доброго времени суток.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как обратиться к дочерней папке с неизвестным именем.
У меня есть директория, имя который я знаю, в ней неопределенное количество дочерних директорий с разными именами, у которых, в свою очередь, есть дочерняя директория, а в этих директориях лежат файлы. Мне нужны именно директории с файлами, что-то, типа "folder/*/**/" (только так не работает) =)

Comment: Если есть какие-то конкретные вопросы по поводу отдельных частей которые вы не понимаете - вот про них и спрашиваете. А то по вашему вопросу вижу, что вы пришли сюда за тем чтобы за вас здесь сделали ВАШУ работу. Где ваш код, показывающий нам что вы пытались достичь требуемого? Рекомендую прочитать в Помощи о нашем сообществе и его целях, а так же о том как задавать здесь вопросы с целью получить на них ответы.

Comment: Виноват, исправился. Так лучше?

Comment: glob вам в помощь https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php

Comment: Спасибо большое, то, что нужно.